# Android Play Store testing tracks equivalent to TestFlight

Tags: android, google-play, testflight

I currently have an app which is being tested with our QA guy as an "Internal Testing" release on the Google Play store. There's only the one QA guy.

Lets say I have version 6 out in Production and version 7 is in Internal Testing. So it's simple enough that after passing testing I can promote 7 to production.

BUT

Meanwhile, during testing, I have already produced version 8 which has some cool new features (but obviously requires more testing). I would like my QA guy to test version 8 and be able to go back to version 7 (still not released) to check there were no regressions

I know that I can promote version 7 to some closed Alpha track, and put version 8 as my Internal Testing version - but I don't know how my QA guy would be able to easily swap back and forth between versions 7 and 8.

In TestFlight, this is actually possible - the QA guy can go back and forth over the recent (within 90 days) releases and swap back and forth.

Doe anyone know a good way of doing this for Android?